# What does it mean by "Rank of A spans dimension b"?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my linear algebra class today the prof said in order to solve the equation

$$A\vec x = b$$

Rank of A should span dimension of b

Rank of A to me is the number of linearly independent columns in A, so it is a number. How can a number span dimension of b?

I don't understand, can someone explain what this claim means?

Comment: Your professor screwed up. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't make sense to me as stated, but probably what was intended is that $b$ should be contained in the column space of $A$.  That's because $A\vec x$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

Edit:  Here's a simple example.

suppose the matrix $A$ is given by

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
5 & 7 & 9 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The rank of this matrix is $2$ because the third column is the sum of the first two ( so not full rank ) and the second is not a multiple of the first ( so rank is greater than one ).  In particular, the columns span a two-dimension subspace.

Quite generally, given a matrix like $A$, the column space is defined as the span of the columns, ie. the set of all vectors

$$
a \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix} + b\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 5 \\ 7 \end{bmatrix} + c\cdot  \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 6 \\ 9 \end{bmatrix}
$$

We can write this more succinctly as

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
5 & 7 & 9 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}
$$

Or, if we let

$$
\vec x = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} 
$$

We can say that the column space is the set of all vectors of the form

$$
A\vec x
$$

where $\vec x$ is any vector.  So, we see, that if

$$
A\vec x = b
$$

is going to have a solution, then $b$ is of the form above, so it is therefore in the span of the column vectors, ie. in the column space of $A$.  So in the case of our matrix $A$, $b$ must lie in a $2$-dimensional subspace of the total space.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Thanks. Yes the prof stated this verbatim and I failed to make sense of it ever since

Comment: Sure.  Give me a few minutes.  It's been awhile since I've tex'd matrices

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $A_{(3\times 3)}$

$$\begin{align}Ax=b \implies \begin{pmatrix}a_{11} &a_{12} & a_{13}\\a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\ a_{31} & a_{32}  &a_{33}  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x_{1}\\x_{2}\\x_{3} \end {pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix}a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2  + a_{13}x_3\\a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2  + a_{23}x_3\\a_{31}x_1 + a_{32}x_2  + a_{33}x_3  \end{pmatrix} \\\\&= x_1c_1 + x_2c_2 + x_3c_3 = b\end{align}$$

where $c_1, c_2, c_3$ are the columns of $A$.

It becomes clear that $b$ is a combination of the columns of $A$, therefore  a combination of vectors that span the space-column of $A$.